# data overwritten while using for loop django

Tags: python, django

I was wondering what went wrong in my code.When I try to save the data it gets overwritten.

```
            if form.is_valid():
                for item in unions_choice_list:
                    announcement = form.save(commit=False)
                    obj = Union.objects.get(pk=item)
                    announcement.union = obj
                    announcement.tittle = request.POST.get('tittle')
                    announcement.message_text = request.POST.get('message_text')
                    tilldate = request.POST.get('till_date')
                    p = unicodedata.normalize('NFKD', tilldate).encode('ascii','ignore')
                    till_date1 = datetime.datetime.strptime(p, '%d %b %Y').date()
                    announcement.till_date = till_date1
                    announcement.type = type
                    announcement.message_from = request.POST.get('message_from')
                    announcement.show_to = 'union'

                    if request.FILES.get('file1') is not None:
                        announcement.file1 = request.FILES['file1']
                    announcement.save()
            else:
                messages.error(request, "Correct the displayed errors")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you call form's `save()` method several times the same model instance will be saved all the time.  To create new instance at the each call you have to set the instance's `pk` to `None`:

```
for item in unions_choice_list:
    form.instance.pk = None
    announcement = form.save(commit=False)
    ...
```

Or, which is the same:

```
for item in unions_choice_list:
    announcement = form.save(commit=False)
    announcement.pk = None
    ...
```